# Where did my silver haskell badge go?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

I have been awarded the silver haskell badge not too long ago. However when I checked [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149392/sepp2k) today to see which bronze tag badges I was awarded, the silver haskell badge was no longer there.

First I thought that maybe a haskell question I answered has been deleted, putting me under 400, and the addition of the bronze badges caused a batch recalc (though I can't imagine why it would). However when looking at the [stats page for haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/stats), I still have more than 400 upvotes, so that's not it.

Edit: Thinking that maybe the stats on the stats page were cached and didn't into account deleted answer, I went through all my haskell answer and I definitely have 420 upvotes from non-deletet, non-community wiki answers (the stats page says 419, but I assume that's because the 420's upvote was from three hours ago and the stats page doesn't update that often). So still no idea, why I lost the badge.

Comment: Do the totals on that page include CW upvotes? If so that could explain it as CW votes don't count towards the badge total.

Comment: @ChrisF: Good idea, but I checked and I only have one haskell CW answer, which has 5 upvotes. Since the stats page says I have 419 upvotes, that wouldn't put me below 400 even if the 419 include the 5 CW upvotes. Also I definitely had the haskell badge before.

Comment: OK - that knocks that idea on the head. I did think that it might have been a combination of CW and a deleted question, coupled with the tag badge reset that probably went with the new bronze level badges.

Comment: Maybe SO has been lazy in their evaluations.

Comment: @Chris: The tag stats page already doesn't include CW votes.

Comment: @BalusC - thanks, I wasn't 100% sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry Sepp, the rules slightly changed, to get a sliver badge you need at least 80 non-wiki answers with a total score of 400. We also remove tag badges that are no longer eligible.

9 more answers on the Haskell tag and you will get that silver badge back.

I will fix up the documentation on the tag page tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, so that explains that.

Comment: Rules changes?  So that's why I saw a few new tag badges when I logged in this morning?

Comment: Don't forget to fix up the tooltips while you're at it.